# Is it possible to change the class name of a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like shown below.

```
<div class="alert alert-info" style="width:224px">
    <strong>Info!</strong> This is a netural alert
</div>
```

Through javascript or jquery, at certain condition, I want to change the class of that div element from `alert alert-info` to `alert alert-success`. Is that possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change class with condition, Use the following sample

```
$('.alert').click(function(){
if(0==0)//your condition goes here
{
  $(this).removeClass('alert-info').addClass('alert-success');
}else{
  $(this).removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-info');
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
document.getElementById("myElementId").className = "MyClass";
```

use space-delimited list to apply multiple classes,if you want to add class here is an example:

```
document.getElementById("myElementId").className += " MyClass";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var divArray = document.getElementsByClassName("alert-info");
var div = divArray[0];
div.className = "alert alert-success";
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery....

```
$('.alert').removeClass('alert-info').addClass('alert-success');
```

.. Unless I'm missing something.